# issues while running Cruise Control with Java and GWT web application

Tags: java, gwt, cruisecontrol

I am working on cruise control with Java & GWT web application.I run cruise control using `./cruisecontrol.sh`. I am using Hibernate. I have used all Hibernate Jars, but I am getting following exception:

```
INFO  ScriptRunner     -      [echo] Project Name: /root/CruiseControl/cruisecontrol-bin-2.8.4/checkout/Demo/buildtest.xml
INFO  ScriptRunner     -     [javac] Compiling 144 source files to /root/CruiseControl/cruisecontrol-bin-2.8.4/checkout/Demo/war/WEB-INF/classes
INFO  ScriptRunner     -     [javac] /root/CruiseControl/cruisecontrol-bin-2.8.4/checkout/Demo/src/com/Project Name/server/domain/Account.java:6: package javax.persistence does not exist
INFO  ScriptRunner     -     [javac] import javax.persistence.Column;
INFO  ScriptRunner     -     [javac]                         ^
INFO  ScriptRunner     -     [javac] /root/CruiseControl/cruisecontrol-bin-2.8.4/checkout/Demo/src/com/Project Name/server/domain/Account.java:7: package javax.persistence does not exist
INFO  ScriptRunner     -     [javac] import javax.persistence.Entity;
INFO  ScriptRunner     -     [javac]                         ^
INFO  ScriptRunner     -     [javac] /root/CruiseControl/cruisecontrol-bin-2.8.4/checkout/Demo/src/com/Project Name/server/domain/Account.java:8: package javax.persistence does not exist
INFO  ScriptRunner     -     [javac] import javax.persistence.FetchType;
INFO  ScriptRunner     -     [javac]                         ^
INFO  ScriptRunner     -     [javac] /root/CruiseControl/cruisecontrol-bin-2.8.4/checkout/Demo/src/com/Project Name/server/domain/Account.java:9: package javax.persistence does not exist
INFO  ScriptRunner     -     [javac] import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
INFO  ScriptRunner     -     [javac]                         ^
INFO  ScriptRunner     -     [javac] /root/CruiseControl/cruisecontrol-bin-2.8.4/checkout/Demo/src/com/Project Name/server/domain/Account.java:10: package javax.persistence does not exist
INFO  ScriptRunner     -     [javac] import static javax.persistence.GenerationType.IDENTITY;
INFO  ScriptRunner     -     [javac]                                ^
INFO  ScriptRunner     -     [javac] /root/CruiseControl/cruisecontrol-bin-2.8.4/checkout/Demo/src/com/Project Name/server/domain/Account.java:10: static import only from classes and interfaces
INFO  ScriptRunner     -     [javac] import static javax.persistence.GenerationType.IDENTITY;
INFO  ScriptRunner     -     [javac] ^
INFO  ScriptRunner     -     [javac] /root/CruiseControl/cruisecontrol-bin-2.8.4/checkout/Demo/src/com/Project Name/server/domain/Account.java:11: package javax.persistence does not exist
INFO  ScriptRunner     -     [javac] import javax.persistence.Id;
INFO  ScriptRunner     -     [javac]                         ^
INFO  ScriptRunner     -     [javac] /root/CruiseControl/cruisecontrol-bin-2.8.4/checkout/Demo/src/com/Project Name/server/domain/Account.java:12: package javax.persistence does not exist
INFO  ScriptRunner     -     [javac] import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
INFO  ScriptRunner     -     [javac]                         ^
INFO  ScriptRunner     -     [javac] /root/CruiseControl/cruisecontrol-bin-2.8.4/checkout/Demo/src/com/Project Name/server/domain/Account.java:13: package javax.persistence does not exist
INFO  ScriptRunner     -     [javac] import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
INFO  ScriptRunner     -     [javac]                         ^
INFO  ScriptRunner     -     [javac] /root/CruiseControl/cruisecontrol-bin-2.8.4/checkout/Demo/src/com/Project Name/server/domain/Account.java:14: package javax.persistence does not exist
INFO  ScriptRunner     -     [javac] import javax.persistence.Table;
INFO  ScriptRunner     -     [javac]                         ^
INFO  ScriptRunner     -     [javac] /root/CruiseControl/cruisecontrol-bin-2.8.4/checkout/Demo/src/com/Project Name/server/domain/Account.java:15: package javax.persistence does not exist
INFO  ScriptRunner     -     [javac] import javax.persistence.Temporal;
INFO  ScriptRunner     -     [javac]                         ^
INFO  ScriptRunner     -     [javac] /root/CruiseControl/cruisecontrol-bin-2.8.4/checkout/Demo/src/com/Project Name/server/domain/Account.java:16: package javax.persistence does not exist
INFO  ScriptRunner     -     [javac] import javax.persistence.TemporalType;
INFO  ScriptRunner     -     [javac]                         ^
INFO  ScriptRunner     -     [javac] /root/CruiseControl/cruisecontrol-bin-2.8.4/checkout/Demo/src/com/Project Name/server/domain/Account.java:21: cannot find symbol
INFO  ScriptRunner     -     [javac] symbol: class Entity
INFO  ScriptRunner     -     [javac] @Entity
INFO  ScriptRunner     -     [javac]  ^
INFO  ScriptRunner     -     [javac] /root/CruiseControl/cruisecontrol-bin-2.8.4/checkout/Demo/src/com/Project Name/server/domain/Account.java:22: cannot find symbol
INFO  ScriptRunner     -     [javac] symbol: class Table
INFO  ScriptRunner     -     [javac] @Table(name = "account")
INFO  ScriptRunner     -     [javac]  ^
INFO  ScriptRunner     -     [javac] /root/CruiseControl/cruisecontrol-bin-2.8.4/checkout/Demo/src/com/Project Name/server/domain/User.java:8: package javax.persistence does not exist
INFO  ScriptRunner     -     [javac] import javax.persistence.Column;
INFO  ScriptRunner     -     [javac]                         ^
INFO  ScriptRunner     -     [javac] /root/CruiseControl/cruisecontrol-bin-2.8.4/checkout/Demo/src/com/Project Name/server/domain/User.java:9: package javax.persistence does not exist
INFO  ScriptRunner     -     [javac] import javax.persistence.Entity;
INFO  ScriptRunner     -     [javac]                         ^
INFO  ScriptRunner     -     [javac] /root/CruiseControl/cruisecontrol-bin-2.8.4/checkout/Demo/src/com/Project Name/server/domain/User.java:10: package javax.persistence does not exist
INFO  ScriptRunner     -     [javac] import javax.persistence.FetchType;
INFO  ScriptRunner     -     [javac]                         ^
INFO  ScriptRunner     -     [javac] /root/CruiseControl/cruisecontrol-bin-2.8.4/checkout/Demo/src/com/Project Name/server/domain/User.java:11: package javax.persistence does not exist
INFO  ScriptRunner     -     [javac] import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
INFO  ScriptRunner     -     [javac]                         ^
INFO  ScriptRunner     -     [javac] /root/CruiseControl/cruisecontrol-bin-2.8.4/checkout/Demo/src/com/Project Name/server/domain/User.java:12: package javax.persistence does not exist
INFO  ScriptRunner     -     [javac] import static javax.persistence.GenerationType.IDENTITY;
INFO  ScriptRunner     -     [javac]                                ^
INFO  ScriptRunner     -     [javac] /root/CruiseControl/cruisecontrol-bin-2.8.4/checkout/Demo/src/com/Project Name/server/domain/User.java:12: static import only from classes and interfaces
INFO  ScriptRunner     -     [javac] import static javax.persistence.GenerationType.IDENTITY;
INFO  ScriptRunner     -     [javac] ^
INFO  ScriptRunner     -     [javac] /root/CruiseControl/cruisecontrol-bin-2.8.4/checkout/Demo/src/com/Project Name/server/domain/User.java:13: package javax.persistence does not exist
INFO  ScriptRunner     -     [javac] import javax.persistence.Id;
INFO  ScriptRunner     -     [javac]                         ^
INFO  ScriptRunner     -     [javac] /root/CruiseControl/cruisecontrol-bin-2.8.4/checkout/Demo/src/com/Project Name/server/domain/User.java:14: package javax.persistence does not exist
INFO  ScriptRunner     -     [javac] import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
INFO  ScriptRunner     -     [javac]                         ^
INFO  ScriptRunner     -     [javac] /root/CruiseControl/cruisecontrol-bin-2.8.4/checkout/Demo/src/com/Project Name/server/domain/User.java:15: package javax.persistence does not exist
INFO  ScriptRunner     -     [javac] import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
INFO  ScriptRunner     -     [javac]                         ^
INFO  ScriptRunner     -     [javac] /root/CruiseControl/cruisecontrol-bin-2.8.4/checkout/Demo/src/com/Project Name/server/domain/User.java:16: package javax.persistence does not exist
INFO  ScriptRunner     -     [javac] import javax.persistence.OneToMany;
INFO  ScriptRunner     -     [javac]                         ^
INFO  ScriptRunner     -     [javac] /root/CruiseControl/cruisecontrol-bin-2.8.4/checkout/Demo/src/com/Project Name/server/domain/User.java:17: package javax.persistence does not exist
INFO  ScriptRunner     -     [javac] import javax.persistence.Table;
INFO  ScriptRunner     -     [javac]                         ^
INFO  ScriptRunner     -     [javac] /root/CruiseControl/cruisecontrol-bin-2.8.4/checkout/Demo/src/com/Project Name/server/domain/User.java:18: package javax.persistence does not exist
INFO  ScriptRunner     -     [javac] import javax.persistence.Temporal;
INFO  ScriptRunner     -     [javac]                         ^
INFO  ScriptRunner     -     [javac] /root/CruiseControl/cruisecontrol-bin-2.8.4/checkout/Demo/src/com/Project Name/server/domain/User.java:19: package javax.persistence does not exist
INFO  ScriptRunner     -     [javac] import javax.persistence.TemporalType;
INFO  ScriptRunner     -     [javac]                         ^
INFO  ScriptRunner     -     [javac] /root/CruiseControl/cruisecontrol-bin-2.8.4/checkout/Demo/src/com/Project Name/server/domain/User.java:24: cannot find symbol
INFO  ScriptRunner     -     [javac] symbol: class Entity
INFO  ScriptRunner     -     [javac] @Entity
INFO  ScriptRunner     -     [javac]  ^
INFO  ScriptRunner     -     [javac] /root/CruiseControl/cruisecontrol-bin-2.8.4/checkout/Demo/src/com/Project Name/server/domain/User.java:25: cannot find symbol
WARN  ScriptRunner     - BUILD FAILED
WARN  ScriptRunner     - /root/CruiseControl/cruisecontrol-bin-2.8.4/cc-build.xml:19: The following error occurred while executing this line:
WARN  ScriptRunner     - /root/CruiseControl/cruisecontrol-bin-2.8.4/checkout/Demo/buildtest.xml:179: Compile failed; see the compiler error output for details.
```

Comment: The clue is in "package javax.persistence does not exist"  There's a problem with your class path. I'd venture a guess that you have not configured the class path properly yet.

Comment: Probably missing ejb3-persistence.jar